# Increase size of an empty JButton in a JToolbar

Tags: java, user-interface, resize, size, jbutton

I wrote the following example-code to explain my problem:

**Toolbar.java**

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JToolBar;

public class Toolbar extends JToolBar {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Toolbar() {
        JButton button = new JButton();
        button.setSize(new Dimension(50,50));
        add(button);
    }
}
```

**MainProgram.java**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel; 

    public class MainProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        Toolbar toolbar = new Toolbar();
        mainPanel.add(toolbar, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The `setSize()` method does not work. The result, with or without `setSize()` is the same.

I also tried with `setPreferredSize()` and `setMinimumSize()`, but is the same, the problem persists. How can I solve?

Comment: Not using a layout manager with swing is a bad idea. It won't directly solve your problem, but you should really look at the available layouts, and start using the one(s) that do what you want.

Comment: what you are seeing is the panel, try setting a layout or a size for your panel

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own class that extends JButton and override getMaximumSize() and getMinimumSize() methods:

Here is the code:

```
public class MyButton extends JButton {
    @Override
    public Dimension getMaximumSize() {
        return new Dimension(32,32);

    }
    @Override
    public Dimension getMinimumSize() {
        return new Dimension(32,32);
    }
}
```

You can read more here: http://www.coderanch.com/t/344902/GUI/java/Setting-default-size-JToolBar-Buttons

Answer (score -1):

`setPrefferedSize(...)` is the correct method when you use a layout manager. JPanel has a default layoutManager of FlowLayout so it should work, and locally it works with `setPrefferedSize(...)`.